# Loading multiple pages with random interval with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hope someone can help, I'm new to JavaScript so please forgive my mistakes.

I'm making a data collector bookmarklet that downloads many pages (>400) and format it. Well, the server that I'm trying to download those pages isn't mine, so I'd not want to raise it's load and be banned or something.

So, I want to set some random interval between each download. As far as I know, jQuery.ajax is an asynchronous function, and doesn't have such an option. Does anyone have any ideas to do this?

Thanks for any assistance - my code is below:

```
upload = function() {
  var getarray = [];

  getarray.push($.ajax({
    // do this for all pages in list
    url: '/01.html'
    success: function() { // format data }
  }));

  $.when.apply($, getarray).done(function() {
    // upload
  });


  ); return;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to perfectly understand the situation, but you can try something like that:

```
getRandom = function(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

upload = function() {
  var getarray = [];

  getarray.push($.ajax({
    // do this for all pages in list
    url: '/01.html'
    success: function() {
    // format data

    var timeout = getRandom(0, 10000);
    // return random value between 0 and 10sec

      setTimeout(function(){
      upload();
      }, timeout);
    }
  }));

  $.when.apply($, getarray).done(function() {
    // upload
  });


  ); return;
};
```